# Nginx / CakePHP /JSON

Tags: php, json, cakephp, nginx

I have recently changed from Apache to Nginx and am running a cakephp2 site.

Part of the site provides a simple API but whenever I try to access the API I now get server 500 errors.

This is the nginx config for the site:

```
server {
      error_log /var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log warn;
      listen 1.2.3.4:80;
      listen [::]:80;
      server_name domain.com www.domain.com 1.2.3.4;
      access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/domain.com-bytes_log bytes_log;
      access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/domain.com combined;
      root /home/findit4/public_html;
      #location / {
      location ~*.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso)$ {
      expires 1M;
      try_files $uri @backend;
      }
      location / {
      error_page 405 = @backend;
      add_header X-Cache "HIT from Backend";
      proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8081;
      include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;
      }
      location @backend {
      internal;
      proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8081;
      include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;
      }
      location ~ .*\.(php|json|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?$ {
      proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8081;
      include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;
      }
      location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
      }
    }
```

This is in the cakePHP routes file.

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
Router::parseExtensions('rss');
Router::mapResources('searchapi', array(
'connectOptions' => array(
    'routeClass' => 'api',
)
));
```

I have checked the mime filetypes and JSON is enabled.

I just can't figure out why it won't server the page.

Comment: I have just manually added a .json file to the /webroot directory and it works fine.

Comment: 500 error is server error. What does Your server log shows? `/var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log`

Comment: Nginx doesn't use .htaccess files. You're going to have to correctly setup your nginx conf files.